# JSPDF Desde una ventana modal

Tags: javascript, angular

Quiero poder convertir mi div en un pdf con el diseño que le tengo dado, si el div no está en una ventana modal me funciona, pero cuando lo meto en una modal de bootstrap me saca el pdf en blanco.

```
    <div id="modal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-max">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">¿Estás seguro?</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div id="content" #content class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <img class="logo-impresion" alt="logo" src="../assets/images/logo-top.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <ul class="datos-paciente-impresion">
                            <li>Prueba</li>
                            <li>Prueba</li>
                            <li>Prueba</li>
                            <li>Prueba</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>Prueba de texto.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="donwloadPDF()">Descargar PDF</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Mi componente ts de Angular

```
      @ViewChild('content') content:ElementRef;

  public donwloadPDF() {
    let doc = new jsPDF();
    let specialEmentHandlers = {
      '#editor': function(element, renderer) {
        return true;
      } 
    };

    let content = this.content.nativeElement;
    doc.fromHTML(content.innerHTML, 15, 15, {
      'width': 100%,
      'elementHandlers': specialEmentHandlers
    });

    doc.save('historia.pdf');
    }
```

Básicamente es una modal, que quiero sacar en un pdf lo que está en la id content, sin embargo si quito todo y en un div pongo por ejemplo "Hola" me lo saca en el pdf perfectamente

**EDITO** Parece que es por la imagen, no la saca en el pdf, alguna idea?

Answer (score -1):

Deberías de poner un `<div class="container">` antes de `<div class="row">`.
trata con eso y me cuentas.